# Easiest way to use LDAP in Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently working on a small project where I have to use LDAP in Eclipse (for Active-Directory access). I want to get the Usernames, create a new user, delete a user.

I actually never worked with LDAP before and I had a few difficulties with finding a well explained step-by-step tutorial to start with. In addition it seems that every tutorial seems to use a different API (OpenLDAP, Apache Directory, UnboundID, Spring Framework ect.), which confuses me. Which API should I use?

I would be very thankful if you would have some hints on how to get started with LDAP.

Comment: It will not be easy to get a recommendation. Use one and ask questions.  Migrating to another tool will not be a big problem.

Comment: If you are permitted to used an API other than JNDI, consider using UnboundID LDAP SDK. It is by far the most complete and easiest to use, and provides many examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My personal choice was UnboindID which is far from perfect, but is more recent than the others, and at least not a dead project like spring-ldap. It certainly has some annoying problems, for example many classes in its API are `final` which is not particularly testing friendly, as you cannot easily create mocks of them.

However if I started a new project now, I would consider using [ldaptive](http://www.ldaptive.org/) which is not another LDAP client implementation, just an API layer above a concrete implementation (provider) to which it delegates LDAP operations. It can work with many different [providers](http://www.ldaptive.org/docs/guide/providers), and seems to offer a much nicer API and good documentation.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be quite what I'm looking for. I'll start with that :)